# How to display a sub menu in hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have a menu with sub menu(vertical). My first `li` is active with the sub menu.
My problem is when I hover in the other `li` I have the sub menu added in my last one.

What I need is:

- when I hover in my menu, to get only the sub menu of my current li
- when my cursor is not hovering in my menu, to get the default sub menu that has the `on class`

this is the link of jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bymb6kvm/2/

this my code :

```
<nav>
                <div id="menuu">
                    <ul class="niveau1">
                        <li><a id="lrf"  class="sousmenu" href="#">Test 1</a>
                            <ul id="lrfH" class="niveau2 on">
                                <li><a href="#">ss test 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">ss test 2</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                       <li><a id="cm" class="sousmenu" href="#">Test 2</a>
                            <ul id="cmH" class="niveau2">
                                <li><a href="#">ss test 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">ss test 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a id="dj" class="sousmenu" href="#">Test 3</a>
                            <ul id="djH" class="niveau2">
                                <li><a href="#">ss test 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">ss test 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

CSS Code

```
#menuu ul{

 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 padding-left:97px;
 line-height:30px;
    }
#menuu li{
    float: left;
    list-style: outside none none;

        }
.sousmenu{

 color: #000 !important;
 text-decoration:none;
 width:150px;
 height:30px;
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.niveau2{
    margin-left: -50px !important;
}
.niveau2 a{
    padding-left:20px !important;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:red ;
}
.sousmenu:hover{
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-bottom-color: #000 !important;
}
#menuu ul ul{
     position:absolute;
     visibility:hidden;
     padding-left:0px;
          }

#menuu ul ul li:hover a{
  color:#000;
}
#menuu ul ul ul{
 left:152px;
 top:-0.5px;
 display:none;
         }

 #menuu ul li:hover ul{
  visibility:visible;   
        }
.niveau2.on{
    visibility:visible !important;
}
```

JS Code

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
                    $('.sousmenu').hover(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var getID=$(this).attr('id');
                        $("#"+getID+"H").css("visibility","visible");
                        $(".on").css("visibility","hidden");
                    });

                });
```

Comment: If you really want to rely on hover, you can dispense with the JavaScript and simply use CSS. See [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/bymb6kvm/5/). (The problem with your fiddle was that you made the submenus visible, but not invisible again on mouseleave.) Working only with hovering is not recommended however, since it won't work on devices that can't detect hovering.

Comment: Try this, Hope this will resolve your issue. http://jsfiddle.net/prajapati/y8r13hg7/

Comment: But i need the first li active and i can see the sub menu for the first time and if i hover the second li the firt one

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.sousmenu').hover(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var getID = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".niveau2").hide();
    $("#" + getID + "H").show();
  });
});
```

```css
#menuu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 97px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

#menuu li {
  float: left;
  list-style: outside none none;
}

.sousmenu {
  color: #000 !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.niveau2 {
  margin-left: -50px !important;
}

.niveau2 a {
  padding-left: 20px !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}

.sousmenu:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: #000 !important;
}

#menuu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

#menuu ul ul li:hover a {
  color: #000;
}

#menuu ul ul ul {
  left: 152px;
  top: -0.5px;
  display: none;
}

#menuu ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
}

.niveau2.on {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div id="menuu">
    <ul class="niveau1">
      <li><a id="lrf" class="sousmenu" href="#">Test 1</a>
        <ul id="lrfH" class="niveau2 on">
          <li><a href="#">ss test 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ss test 2</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a id="cm" class="sousmenu" href="#">Test 2</a>
        <ul id="cmH" class="niveau2">
          <li><a href="#">ss test 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ss test 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a id="dj" class="sousmenu" href="#">Test 3</a>
        <ul id="djH" class="niveau2">
          <li><a href="#">ss test 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ss test 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[View on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hemnathmouli/nkzq6oyr/2/)

Comment: Thanks for reply but i think they have a problem when i hover in second `li` it's work perfect but when my cursor is out of my menu i don't have the default menu thas is active the default on contains a `on class`